# Congruent integers and modulus

Tags: modulus

I'm new to the topic here :/
Could anyone please tell me how to solve the following?
Show that 36^2004 + 17^768 x 27^412 is divisible by 19.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Simple identities can be used to solve the above, the important of them being:

```
(a + b) mod c = a mod c + b mod c
```

Also,

```
ab mod c = (a mod c)*(b mod c)
```

This can be used to solve very big exponents also, for example, if you are to solve:

```
24^3100 mod 19
```

You could probably break it up as:

```
24^(310*100) mod 19
```

which can be further written as:

```
24^310 mod 19 x 24^100 mod 19
```

You can further break it down to values you could actually compute and solve. For example, if you keep on breaking down 100, you could end up solving

```
(24^4 mod 19)^25
```

and so on and so forth. Since this is a homework question, I can only provide hints and not the complete solution.

You can also do it with the fast exponentiation method where the exponent is expressed in powers of two.